# with open file skip file not exist if not opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The code will walk through a group of HTML files named `0001.html`, `0002.html`, etc. The code will open files and scrap but if the file does not exist, then I want to make a statement that if the file example 0010.html not exist skip it so the statement will be after `with open()`.

```
c = 1
while c <= n:

    path1=os.path.join(path,"Chapter " + str(c))
    os.mkdir(path1)
    if c<10:
       z='0000'+str(c)
    elif c>=10:
        z='000'+str(c)
    elif c>=1000:
        z='00'+str(c)

    print(z)
    with open(z + '.html','r') as fp:
            contents =fp.read()
            soup= BeautifulSoup(contents,'lxml')
            title = soup.find('h1')
            link = soup.find_all('p')
    chapter=path1+"\\chapter"+str(c)+ ".txt"
    with open(chapter,'w') as f:
        # add statement here
```

do I can do it with try and exception like that

```
try:
  the scrape code
exception:
  continue:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're completely right. You just need to wrap your open file code block with a try except block. Something like this:-

```
try:
    with open(z + '.html','r') as fp:
        ...
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```